# html2canvas jspdf en internetexplorer 11

Tags: javascript, canvas, promesas, internet-explorer, jspdf

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un botón que tiene que realizar una captura de pantalla y generar un pdf. Uso las librerías html2canvas (para hacer la captura de pantalla) y la librería jsPDF, para convertir la imagen en pdf. En los navegadores chrome y firefox funciona sin problemas, pero no funciona en internet explorer 11. ¿Alguna idea? ¿pollyfill, promesas, e6-promise.js?

```
 screenshot:function(){


     var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm','a4');
     html2canvas($("#TexturedClass"), {
         onrendered: function(canvas){
             var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
             var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;    
             var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
             doc.addImage(imgData,'PNG',0,0,width,height);      
         }
     }).then(function(){
         html2canvas($("#tableSemiFinished"),{
             onrendered: function(canvas){
                 doc.addPage();
                 var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
                 var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;    
                 var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
                 doc.addImage(imgData,'PNG',0,0,width,0);
                 doc.save('TexturedReport.pdf')    ;
             }
         })                       
      })
```

Comment: fíjate este hilo https://stackoverflow.com/q/36016327/1423096 ahi recomiendan bluebird o babel

Comment: Añadiendo el script de la librería pollyfil, si funciona en internet explorer.<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>