# como crear y descargar una imagen con html2canvas de un div desfasado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una pregunta.

Quiero crear y guardar una imagen de un `div` el cual es una gráfica de `gantt`:
[image: Grafica de gantt en el div "Grafica"]

Entonces la gráfica anterior es la que quiero hacer imagen, para ello destaco que no tengo experiencia en `JS` y cuando he buscado algún código para ayudarme, por alguna razón no me funciona.

```
<div id="Grafica">
  {!! $gantt !!}
</div>
```

ese es el `div` desfasado que deseo hacer imagen y este es el código que he intentado usar para hacerlo:

```
function capturar2(){
html2canvas(
  document.querySelector("#Grafica img")).then(canvas => {
      var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = image;
      a.download = 'Diagrama.png';
      a.click();
  });
}
```

Problema, me funciono en modo local pero solo captura lo que se ve y en chrome es el único navegador que me funciona, lo subí a un servidor y ahora no descarga nada en ningún navegador. Alguna recomendación?

Comment: tal vez necesitas un polyfill para otros navegadores fijate en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/153529/81450 si hay alguna pista

Comment: aquí hay otro ejemplo de código para descargar un html2canvas https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158786/81450